# Is the sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lfloor n\pi \rfloor x^n$ a rational function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, power-series, rational-functions

I was reading [this paper by L.J. Mordell](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-04/S0002-9939-1961-0125947-0/S0002-9939-1961-0125947-0.pdf) (original paper by Morris Newman). I am trying to apply first theorem from the paper with $f(x)=x$ and $k=\pi$. So the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lfloor n\pi \rfloor x^n$ must not converge to a rational function for $|x|<1$.

But it seems that the series converges to a rational function as the series can be written as $3x+6x^2+9x^3+...=\frac{3x}{(x-1)^2}$ after we evaluate $\lfloor n\pi \rfloor$ for each $n$? Am I doing something wrong with the evaluation of $\lfloor n\pi \rfloor$?

EDIT: David found my mistake. Now the question is can we find the sum of this series or show that the sum is not a rational function without Mordell's result?

Comment: $\lfloor8\pi\rfloor=25$ not $24$.

Comment: Ops! Such a trivial blunder!

Comment: The question of whether the sum is a rational function is equivalent to the question of whether $a_n = \lfloor n \pi \rfloor$ satisfies a linear constant-coefficient recurrence relation for $n$ sufficiently large, which in turn is equivalent to the question of whether $a_n$ is a linear combination of sequences of the form $n^p \alpha^n$ for $p \in \mathbb{N}, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Using series of floor function, we can write $\lfloor n\pi \rfloor=\frac{-1}{2}+n\pi+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{2kn\pi^2}}{k}}{\pi}$. Can we prove from this that it doesn't satisfy a linear constant-coefficient recurrence?

Comment: @DanielSchepler , I didn't understand your last equivalence with $n^p \alpha^n$?